# Using a cellular modem vs a cellular router to connect to the internet

Tags: linux, networking, router, modem, ppp

I am working on a project using an embedded Rasberry Pi computer running Debian to communicate with the internet using 4G.

I have used a cellular modem at first, whereby we communicate with the modem from the Pi using PPP, a layer 2 protocol. The Pi then receives a dynamic IP address from the Internet Service Provider.

However we are going to replace the cellular modem with a cellular router instead. I believe that the device will have a router and modem all in one.

How will the communication be implemented then from the computer to this router? I'm guessing the router already does the work of communicating directly with the modem so it should make it easier.

Does the router obtain the IP address from the ISP automatically, or does the computer still get it? So in order for me to communicate with the outside world via the internet, I must communicate with the router's IP address? This confuses me a bit.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the router obtain the IP address from the ISP automatically, or does the computer still get it?

Usually the uplink connection is established and the address is obtained by the router. Your own devices will usually obtain router-assigned "local" addresses.

> So in order for me to communicate with the outside world via the internet, I must communicate with the router's IP address? This confuses me a bit.

This works exactly the same way as with all other routers, including perhaps the one you've got at home.

For inbound connections via IPv4, yes, other hosts will communicate with the router's IP address (obtained from the ISP). The router will use its configured "port forwarding" aka DNAT rules to decide which internal address to forward the packet to.

For inbound connections via IPv6, the router additionally obtains a range of public addresses and distributes those to your devices. This allows other hosts to communicate directly with your device's own address... assuming IPv6 is supported in the first place, that is.

(Note that there could be exceptions for IPv4, depending on agreement with the ISP: they *might* provide you with multiple addresses – one for the router, and then for devices themselves – but this would need manual configuration.)

For outbound connections there's no change in application behavior; your programs *do not* use the router's IP address for anything. They just specify the real destination IP address, and the operating system uses its routing table to resolve it to the correct interface and MAC address.

(The router itself then does the same, and the next router also, until the final destination is reached.)

Comment: Thanks. But I guess , on my Rasberry Pi, the default gateway must be set to the IP address of the router correct?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in the Raspberry Pi's routing table. Usually happens automatically when the Pi obtains its own address via DHCP.